# Parent element incorrectly calculates the width of their children

Tags: html, css

Please look at the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7wwobsqq/1/

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>

.parent {
    max-width: 300px;
    background: grey;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

My problem is that the parent element computes its width, without paying attention to the fact that the blocks are on different lines.

Then for this example, I would like to parent has been narrowed to the maximum width of the block. Also, if the children are able to fit on one line, they should be there.
To help you understand what I mean, take a look at the screenshots:
http://s21.postimg.org/ioldq2blj/stack_Overflow.jpg

Currently I am using ul->li elements, not div's, as on jsfiddle page, but in this case their behaviors are equally.

Thanks for the comments.

Here are additional examples. In the first case, we see the two elements aligned. In the second case, the second child is moved down, because the parent element has max-width. We got an empty space on the right. 
Screenshot - http://s4.postimg.org/p4h4bj86l/stack_Overflow2.jpg http://jsfiddle.net/7wwobsqq/8/ http://jsfiddle.net/7wwobsqq/9/

```
<ul class="parent">
   <li class="child first">
   </li>
   <li class="child second">
   </li>
</ul>

.parent {
    border: 1px dashed #ccc;
    float: left;
    min-width: 333px;
    max-width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
    margin: 2px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgb(255, 216, 87);
}

.first {
    width: 126px;
    height: 127px;
}

.second {
  width: 207px;
  height: 122px;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "children are able to fit on one line"? your picture is referencing a child element not present in the first two pictures

Comment: you should also recreate your fiddle as close as possible to your situation to demonstrate the quirky behavoir. while <li>s and <div>s are both block elements, they still have quirks unique to them. I would also suggest adding in the textarea since one of your comments below seems to suggest you're using textareas as well

Comment: Here are additional examples. In the first case, we see the two elements aligned. In the second case, the second member is moved down, because the parent element has max-width and we get an empty space on the right.
http://jsfiddle.net/7wwobsqq/8/
http://jsfiddle.net/7wwobsqq/9/
And screenshot - http://s4.postimg.org/p4h4bj86l/stack_Overflow2.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Your `.parent` div is always going to be 100% width, becuase that is what happens when you have an element that is `display: block`. It will take up the width of it's parent element. Right now `max-width` is controlling the width of your `.parent` element, because it wants to fill it's parent, but it can't.

You probably want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7wwobsqq/1/).

Get rid of `overflow: hidden` on your `.parent`, it's unnecessary.

Also, you need to set `display: inline-block` on both the `.parent` and `.child` elements. This gives you all the styling perks of a block element, but tells it that you need it to be on the same line as it's siblings.

Comment: I tried it, here is a screenshot http://s4.postimg.org/p4h4bj86l/stack_Overflow2.jpg

Now I make another demo in jsfiddle.

Comment: I've added more examples after my question above.

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: inline-block;` to the `.parent`, and remove `float: left` from `.child`, and you'll get your expected behavior:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3x42wn25/)

---

Here's why your code doesn't work:

W3C defines the [algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins) for determining the dimensions of HTML elements.  Here, `.parent` is a "[block-level, non-replaced element in normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#blockwidth)."

[First](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-widths), a *tentative* width is calculated ignoring the `max-width` property.  For a block-level element, this would be the width of its parent minus margins – in this case the width of the document body.

If this width is *greater* than `max-width`, then `max-width` becomes the width – in this case, `300px`.

It's as simple as that.  Adding a `max-width` to a `div` automatically sets the `div` to be that width, regardless of content.  You can see that in this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o90Lhdy1/)** (no content) as well as this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3x42wn25/1/) (content overflowing the parent).

---

Here's why my code works:

Adding `display: inline-block;` to the `.parent` makes it an "[inline-block, non-replaced element in normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inlineblock-width)."

Since there's not a defined width, the [shrink-to-fit algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float) is now used, which (true to its name), *shrinks* the container to *fit* its content.

Comment: It'd be nice to explain why

Comment: @RickHitchcock well for the display: inline-block, its because the content is trying to stretch the full width of the container (parent in this case) as a block element (block elements "fill up the entire line") but if you put it inline then it'll behave like in a row if possible. but inline-block is a new css3 feature to make them behave like a block (one element per row, but also like inline elements if there is room

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it is not a complete decision of my question.

Comment: I've added more examples after my question above.

Comment: Remove `min-width` from `.parent`, remove `float` from `.child`, and change `display: inline-block` to `display: block`:  http://jsfiddle.net/ecs4tLkL/

Comment: Thank for your decision.
In this case, we can locate multiple childs in one line and we can not specify a minimum width for the parent. (For example, in the beginning there are no blocks in the parent and we are adding childs to them.)

Comment: It's fine to have a `min-width` on the parent.  In your example, it happened to be the same as the `max-width`, which prevented it from shrinking to fit its children.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken.
we can   not*   locate multiple childs in one line in your example.

Comment: And this is a problem because it does not fully meet the original question.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  In http://jsfiddle.net/7wwobsqq/9/, there's not enough room for the children to be side by side, but if you set `max-width` greater than 350px, there will be, and the parent will shrink to fit both of them.

Comment: Yes, there is not enough room for the children to be side by side, but width of container = max width and we see an empty space on the right

Answer (score 0):

Probably you wanted to ask about this layout (added inline-block to parent) This is the classic shrink-to-fit solution.

```css
.parent {
    max-width: 300px;
    background: grey;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}

.child {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.parent:hover .child {
    width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Hover to see it changing.

It behaves this way because there isn't a loop in the render algorithm (that could cause infinite loops, by the way)

The parent is being stretched, trying to make room for the children. When it gets the maximum width, the child goes to the next row, but the width of the parent won't be re-calculated